# silverlight service cross domain error

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I type my wcf (svc) service name in browser and the following is displayed:
Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.
....
....

my service address:
http://www.farasanjtelemetry.com/service1.svc

but when I run my test SL app (which calls this service) I get cross domain error, what's going wrong?
binding? end point? cross domain files? I've copied two XML files in my server C:\inetpub\wwwroot and also beside my service1.svc, what should I check more?
my test SL app address:
http://www.farasanjtelemetry.com/SLServiceTestTestPage.html

what should I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your ServiceReferences.ClientConfig, you didn´t update your endpoint address. The silverlight app is searching the service at

```
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:80/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicEndpoint" contract="ServiceReference1.Service1"
            name="CustomBinding_Service1" />
```

Correct it and you should be fine.

BTW: Check your acceptance rate, otherwise it might prevent other users from helping you in the future

Replace your ServiceReferences.ClientConfig with the following:

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="CustomBinding_Service1">
                <binaryMessageEncoding />
                <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://www.farasanjtelemetry.com/service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            contract="ServiceReference1.Service1" name="ServiceReference1.Service1" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Than your app will work, given you can reach http://www.farasanjtelemetry.com/service1.svc from your machine.

Comment: thanks dominik, but now I get another error: The underlying channel factory cannot be created.... it is my clientconfig:endpoint address="http://localhost:80/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicEndpoint" contract="ServiceReference1.Service1"
                name="CustomBinding_Service1" />

Comment: First, I didn´t mean to accept the answer if it didn´t help you. Check your previous questions and mark the appropiate ones as answered. Second, whats the inner exception of the one you see?

Comment: ok dominik I'll do so certainly, thanks for your warning, I want to know what is a correct client.config? is there any where I can a good and standard one? what do you mean by inner exception?

Comment: @user833139 See my updated answer, your wcf client config was broken. I suggest you spend some time exploring WCF Basics. Don´t forget to mark as answer if it helped ;)

Comment: thanks dear Dominik, you've really helped me, I'll certainly read more about WCF basics, thanks 1000 times! now I should try to implement SQL in my service

Comment: One final word of advice here. Your service is reachable for everyone via internet. Take a minute and secure it against unauthorized access before some script kiddy drops your database.